# JPA @OneToOne throws Error when mapped to an abstract @Entity with subclasses

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, one-to-one

I have a problem when an Entity is mapped to another Entity which has a direct implementation on its subclasses. See sample mapping below:

```
@Entity
class Location {
      @OneToOne
      @JoinColumn(...)
      private Person person;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="person_type",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
abstract class Person {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("M")
class Man extends Person {
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("W")
class Woman extends Person {
    ...
}
```

Now, this is what I have on my database table:

location-table:
id=1, person_id=1
person-table:
id=1,person_type="M"

When I retrieve the Location using entity manager, hibernate throws an exception saying that i cannot instantiate an abstract class or an interface.

```
Location location = entityManager.find(Location.class, 1L);
```

Hibernate throws this error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface: Person
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:630)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:195)
at ......
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:98)
at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$TestListenerInvokingMethodRoadie.runTestMethod(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:174)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:79)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:87)
at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$TestListenerInvokingMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:156)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:77)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:42)
at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:95)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.access$000(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:44)
at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$1.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:62)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: What is the datatype of your discriminator column in the db?

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace?

Comment: Have you tried @MappedSuperclass instead of @Entity on Person?

Comment: [This forum post](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=974073) may help as well although it's from 2007. Essentially, it suggests to add a dummy discriminator value to the abstract base class.

Comment: @Martin - I want to store those entities on the same table and I guess @MappedSuperclass cannot be mapped on an entity relationship e.g. @OneToOne

Comment: I have tried your example with EclipseLink as is and I'm not getting any exception. Maybe it's a problem with how you have initialized the data? Is there any entry without a value in the discriminator column in the person table?

Answer (score 4):

This did the trick for me, using hibernate as persistence provider.

```
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
```

Answer (score 2):

From [The Java EE 6 Tutorial - Entity Inheritence](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html#bnbqo):

> Any mapping or relationship
>   annotations in non-entity superclasses
>   are ignored.

So you seem to be correct that you have to annotate the `Person` class with `@Entity` to associate it with a `Location` via `@OneToOne`.

From the [@MappedSuperclass javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html)

> A class designated with the
>   MappedSuperclass annotation can be
>   mapped in the same way as an entity
>   except that the mappings will apply
>   only to its subclasses since no table
>   exists for the mapped superclass
>   itself.

So you couldn't use `@MappedSuperclass` on Person, then map it with the `@OneToOne`, since there would be no Person table.

Seems like the JPA annotations you are using are correct.  Have you tried @Martin Klinke's suggestion of a dummy discriminator value for the `Person` class?

Comment: This solved my problem, I forgot @Entity on the subclass and received the same error until I added it to the child class.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in my comment above, I have tried the same with EclipseLink and it works.

After creating some test data, I've cleared the discriminator value of a person entry in the DB and now I get a similar exception when trying to load the associated location. EclipseLink's message is a little bit more descriptive:

```
Exception Description: Missing class for indicator field value [] of type [class java.lang.String].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.mklinke.webtest.domain.Person --> [DatabaseTable(PERSON)])
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.missingClassForIndicatorFieldValue(DescriptorException.java:937)
at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.InheritancePolicy.classFromValue(InheritancePolicy.java:355)
at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.InheritancePolicy.classFromRow(InheritancePolicy.java:342)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:485)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:456)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:723)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadObjectQuery.java:766)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:451)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1080)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:808)
...
```

The mapping seems to work, so unless the data is "corrupt" (which it isn't in your case as you said), it's probably a bug or at least different behavior in Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

I found this kind of problem solves itself if the Entity classes implement `Serializable`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error message with the following structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Person {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long     id;

}
```

with a concrete child instance

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("REALPERSON")
public class RealPerson extends Person{ etc... }
```

and a class that has a field referencing the abstract class:

```
public class SomeClass() {
  @OneToOne
  private Person person;
}
```

The following changes fixed the problem for me:

1. Change the `@OneToOne` to `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`
2. Change the `@GeneratedValue` to `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)`

UPDATE: I also found I was not saving the RealPerson object before linking it to SomeClass. So now that I first save the instance first, the `cascade` attribute is no longer required

Answer (score 0):

I run similar code to this, with a couple of differences. Firstly, I place the Abstract class behind an interface. Secondly, I explicitly define the targetEntity for the @OnetoOne mapping. An example would be:

```
@Entity
class Location {
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = AbstractPerson.class)
    @JoinColumn(...)
    private Person person;
}

public interface Person {
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="person_type",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
abstract class AbstractPerson implements Person {
}
```

Here I've renamed your Person abstract class to 'AbstractPerson' for clarity. Took quite a bit of playing around with to get it working, I hope it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @ForceDiscriminator to Person. Without this annotation Hibernate often tries to instantiate the parent class, ignoring the discriminator that should tell it which child class to instantiate.